# Conditionally set `dired-listing-switches` locally, but `nil` remotely

Tags: emacs, dired

The following setting works great locally (OSX), but prevents Emacs from properly displaying directories/ files on the remote server (Linux):

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "-aBhl --group-directories-first")
```

I log in to the remote server with:

```
C-x C-f /ssh:user@server:/home/user/
```

So `dired-listing-switches` needs to be set locally, but `nil` remotely.  How can this be accomplished programmatically?

Comment: Untested, but nowadays `C-h i g (emacs)Connection Variables` might be a viable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this only for interactive use of `dired` and not also for programmatic calls to function `dired`, then you do not need to (and so should probably not) advise `dired`.

Instead, just define a new command, `my-dired`, which tests its arg using `file-remote-p` and then calls `dired` using the appropriate switches.  Then remap `dired` to your command, for key bindings. Similarly, for `dired-other-window`.

If you want to allow for similar prefix arg behavior to that of `dired`, you can do that as well. E.g., if `current-prefix-arg` then read and use the switches provided by the user, else do as described above: test arg and set switches accordingly.

For example (untested):

```
(defun my-dired (dirname &optional switches)
  "..."
  (interactive
   (let* ((dir  (if (next-read-file-uses-dialog-p)
                    (read-directory-name "Dired (directory): "
                                         nil default-directory nil)
                  (read-file-name "Dired (directory): "
                                  nil default-directory nil)))
          (sws  (if current-prefix-arg
                    (read-string "Dired listing switches: "
                                 dired-listing-switches)
                  (if (file-remote-p dir)
                      "-al"
                    "-aBhl --group-directories-first"))))
     (list dir sws)))
  (switch-to-buffer (dired-noselect dirname switches)))
```

Remember that advising changes the function you advise. Ask yourself whether you want to do that in general or just for interactive use of the function. If the latter, then you typically do not need or want to advise the function - just define and use a different command.

Comment: Thank you -- I'll give that a try and report back later on today.

Comment: Here is my tentative thinking:  `(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (if (file-remote-p dired-directory) (setq-local dired-actual-switches "-al") (setq-local dired-actual-switches "-aBhl --group-directories-first")) ))`  I need to add something for `(or switches . . .)` just in case there are `switches` instead of `dired-listing-switches` . . .

Comment: I doubt that will help you - `dired-mode-hook` is run at the very end of `dired-mode`. 


My suggestion is above: define a command that checks the `DIRNAME` argument and sets the `SWITCHES` accordingly. Others might have other suggestions, but that is mine.

Comment: I added an example (untested). I just tweaked the existing code for `dired-read-dir-and-switches` slightly.

Comment: Thanks for the sample function.  We need to define `str` -- `(void-variable str)`.  The proposed `dired-mode-hook` in the comment above *does* work, but I'm not yet sure why -- I agree with you that it gets run at the very tail end of `dired-mode` -- perhaps the hook is run once again (by another function) just prior to the dired buffer being generated . . . and that may be the reason why the hook works in this particular case.

Comment: For `str`: Just remove it or bind it to a string such as `""` (or `" in other window"` if you use `switch-to-buffer-other-window`). See `dired-read-dir-and-switches`.

Comment: Back to my original question: Do you want to change `dired` behavior for non-interactive use also? That's what using such a hook does. I think you instead want to just define a different command, and leave all non-interactive uses of function `dired` alone.

Comment: I have not yet been able to locate the specific `dired` function that is responsible for the behavior I see when opening a remote directory with `C-x C-f /ssh:user@server:/home/user/` -- that is the reason why I couldn't decide which `dired` function to modify.  It *might* be a `non-interactive` dired function that needs modification.

Comment: (I removed `str` from the code above.) What remote-opening behavior are you referring to? Have you *tried* the code above? `dired` should itself do the right thing, regardless of whether its arg is a local or remote directory. I thought that the only thing you wanted to do was pass different switches for the remote-dir case. Sounds like the question is changing now...(?)

Comment: Your revised example works well.  I had only previously seen an example of `find-file` when opening a remote directory and a `dired` buffer gets opened when that occurs.  That is why I was confused regarding what `dired` function was being used behind the scenes.  I created a function, using your example, which works well:  `(defun lawlist-remote-server-login () (interactive) (my-dired "/ssh:lawlist@12.34.56.789:/home/lawlist/public_html/"))`  Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated!  :)

Answer (score 3):

As much as I wanted to use a hook, none of the dired hooks seemed to allow this customization because dired tries to be a little lazy as to how it loads things.

Advice will allow you to switch the value of dired-listing-switches programmatically by allowing us to surround the body of the `dired' function with more code.

The first value passed into dired is the directory, so you can use `file-remote-p` to determine if it's a server location. You access the args to the function you are advising by using `ad-get-arg <index>`

```lisp
(defadvice dired (around no-switches-for-server-file activate)
  "When opening dired for a remote location, use the default switches"
  (let ((dired-listing-switches (if (file-remote-p (ad-get-arg 0))
                                    "-al" ;; the default switches
                                  dired-listing-switches)))
    ad-do-it))
```

If this is your first encounter with function advice give the docs a read.

<kbd>M-:</kbd> (info "(elisp) Advising Functions") <kbd>enter</kbd>

I do not believe you want the variable to be nil, rather the default value. When I tried using nil, dired would give me an error. If you don't even want the default value, switch it out for an empty string.

Comment: Thank you very much.  My very preliminary testing necessitated removing the setting of `(setq dired-listing-switches "-aBhl --group-directories-first")` and replacing your `dired-listing-switches` with `"-aBhl --group-directories-first"`.  The stock `M-x dired` works correctly locally, and the directories / files are displayed correctly remotely.  My custom open-file / display-buffer function failed, so it may need to be tweaked a bit.  You have certainly hit the nail on the head with `(if (file-remote-p (ad-get-arg 0)) . . .`  I'll work on it some more later this evening and report back.

Comment: What is your custom ope-file / display-buffer function? And how is that interacting with opening dired buffers?

Comment: The conflict between your answer and my error message *may* have been caused by this function:  `(defun lawlist-custom-open-file () (interactive) (if buffer-file-name (dired nil) (cond ((eq system-type 'darwin) (dired "~/.0.data")) ((eq system-type 'windows-nt) (dired "y:/")))) (lawlist-add-buffer))`

Comment: At this time, the following tentative solution (based on your usage of `file-remote-p`) is working well: `(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (if (file-remote-p dired-directory) (setq-local dired-actual-switches "-al") (setq-local dired-actual-switches "-aBhl --group-directories-first")) ))` I assume that the `dired-mode-hook` is being run after the variable `dired-directory` has been determined